# Listview for my records if I appear in any child records

Tags: list-view, child-to-parent

Suppose we have an A SObject, A has a user child SObject. Now we want to build a list view to show my A records if I am one of the child users linking to the A record. And this needs to be done using listview instead of LWC.

When we come to this scenario, we don't think there is any out-of-box way resolving this. So we thought about using a trigger to populate the ids of the users into one custom field in A. Then we can filter. This can be a solution. But wondering if there is any better way resolving this.

Comment: I don't think I understand your datamodel. If User is the child object (and assuming this is a custom User object, because the standard User object cannot have any lookup fields) then how can 1 User have multiple A records linked to it?

Comment: @GuyClairbois Sorry, I was trying to simply the model a little bit when stating the question. The actual model is we have a SOjbect B which is the child object of A (has lookup to A). B also has one user in it (say name or look up to user). We want to find out the list when the current user is in any of the B records

Comment: Ah, I see. If you want to use a List View, you can only filter on fields on object A. So there needs to be something in a field on object A, which means your suggested solution is most probably the only one.
The only alternative that might work is if Users should only see the object A records that their user is connected to (via object B). In that case you could use Sharing (instead of field filters) to show/hide only the relevant object A records in the list view.